# Trac report closed ticket by date

Tags: report, trac

I need a Trac report that show me all closed ticket grouped by closing date. 
Is this possible ?

I've tried to use this statement but with no luck

`SELECT component, 
    summary,
    priority, 
    time AS created,
    strftime("%yyyy-%m-%d",time) AS __GROUP__, 
    t.description AS _description,
    reporter AS reporter
    FROM ticket t
    LEFT JOIN milestone m ON m.name = t.milestone
    WHERE t.status = 'closed'
ORDER BY m.due DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query that works (tested in Trac 1.1.1):

```
SELECT date(MAX(tc.time/1000000), 'unixepoch') as __group__,
       ticket, summary
  FROM ticket_change tc
  LEFT JOIN ticket ON tc.ticket=id
 WHERE field='status'
   AND newvalue='closed'
 GROUP by ticket
 ORDER by tc.time
```

Critical as well as tricky bits are

- finding the LAST closed date
- properly formatting dates by converting time stamps to string without interfering with 'automagical' time-stamp-to-date-string conversion for reports

Answer (score 1):

The time at which the ticket was closed can be obtained in the `ticket_change` table by searching for entries with `field=resolution` and `newvalue=closed`. There could be multiple such entries for a single ticket if it was reopened and then closed again. The tables are documented [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/DatabaseSchema#DatabaseSchema0.12). See also [#8728](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/8728).